# Finding required placeholders in Tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Tensorflow, is there a way to find all placeholder tensors that are required to evaluate a certain output tensor?  That is, is there a function that will return all (placeholder) tensors that must be fed into `feed_dict` when `sess.run(output_tensor)` is called ?

Here's an example of what I'd like to do, in pseudocode:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=())
b = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=())
c = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=())
d = a + b
f = b + c

# This should return [a,b] or [a.name,b.name]
d_input_tensors = get_dependencies(d)

# This should return [b,c] or [b.name,c.name]
f_input_tensors = get_dependencies(f)
```

**EDIT:**  To clarify, I am not (necessarily) looking for all of the placeholders in the graph, just the ones that are required for defining a particular output tensor.  The desired placeholders are likely to be only a subset of all placeholders in the graph.

Comment: For getting all placeholders in the graph, there is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44371483/4834515. as for getting dependencies... no idea.

Comment: @Seven I'd like to get just the dependencies, not all of the placeholders.  I'll edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tinkering and discovering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257015/how-can-i-list-all-tensorflow-variables-a-node-depends-on) nearly identical SO question, I came up with the following solution:

```
def get_tensor_dependencies(tensor):

    # If a tensor is passed in, get its op
    try:
        tensor_op = tensor.op
    except:
        tensor_op = tensor

    # Recursively analyze inputs
    dependencies = []
    for inp in tensor_op.inputs:
        new_d = get_tensor_dependencies(inp)
        non_repeated = [d for d in new_d if d not in dependencies]
        dependencies = [*dependencies, *non_repeated]

    # If we've reached the "end", return the op's name
    if len(tensor_op.inputs) == 0:
        dependencies = [tensor_op.name]

    # Return a list of tensor op names
    return dependencies
```

**Note**: This will not only return placeholders, but also variables and constants.  If `dependencies = [tensor_op.name]` is replaced by `dependencies = [tensor_op.name] if tensor_op.type == 'Placeholder' else []`, then only placeholders will be returned.