# Batch Normalization at inference time in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, normalization

I have loaded the trained checkpoint file for inference. I have extracted the beta, moving mean and moving variance and all weights from the model. In batch normalization, I getting the wrong result when I am manually calculating the output of `batch_normalization`.
[UPDATED]

Here I am sharing my code which loads the checkpoint, print the input to the batch normalization, print beta, moving mean and moving variance and print the output of batch normalization on the console.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import os

def main():
    with tf.Session() as sess:        

        #[INFO] code for loading checkpoint
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("./bag-model-34000.meta")
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("./"))
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        input_place = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input/image_input:0')
        op = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output/image_output:0')
        #----------------------------------------------------------------------

        #[INFO] generating input data which is equal to input tensor shape
        #----------------------------------------------------------------------
        input_data = np.random.randint(255, size=(1,320,240, 3)).astype(float)
        #----------------------------------------------------------------------

        #[INFO] code to get all tensors_name
        #----------------------------------------------------------------------
        operations = sess.graph.get_operations()
        ind = 0;
        tens_name = []  # store all tensor name in list
        for operation in operations:
            #print(ind,"> ", operation.name, "=> \n", operation.values())

            if (operation.values()): 
                name_of_tensor = str(operation.values()).split()[1][1:-1]

            tens_name.append(name_of_tensor)
            ind = ind + 1
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------

        #[INFO] printing Input to batch normalization, beta, moving mean and moving variance
        # so I can calculate manually batch normalization output
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------   
        tensor_number = 0
        for tname in tens_name:         # looping through each tensor name

            if tensor_number <= 812:      # I am interested in first 812 tensors
                tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name(tname)
                tensor_values = sess.run(tensor, feed_dict={input_place: input_data})
                print("tensor: ", tensor_number, ": ", tname, ": \n\t\t", tensor_values.shape)


                # [INFO] 28'th tensor its name is "input/conv1/conv1_1/separable_conv2d:0"
                # the output of this tensor is input to the batch normalization
                if tensor_number == 28:
                    # here I am printing this tensor output
                    print(tensor_values)            # [[[[-0.03182551  0.00226904  0.00440771 ... 
                    print(tensor_values.shape)      # (1, 320, 240, 32)


                # [INFO] 31'th tensor its name is "conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/beta:0"
                # the output of this tensor is all beta
                if tensor_number == 31:
                    # here I am printing this beta's
                    print(tensor_values)            # [ 0.04061257 -0.16322449 -0.10942575 ...
                    print(tensor_values.shape)      # (32,)


                # [INFO] 35'th tensor its name is "conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0"
                # the output of this tensor is all moving mean
                if tensor_number == 35:
                    # here I am printing this moving means
                    print(tensor_values)            # [-0.0013569   0.00618145  0.00248459 ...
                    print(tensor_values.shape)      # (32,)


                # [INFO] 39'th tensor its name is "conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0"
                # the output of this tensor is all moving_variance
                if tensor_number == 39:
                    # here I am printing this moving variance
                    print(tensor_values)            # [4.48082483e-06 1.21615967e-05 5.37582537e-06 ...
                    print(tensor_values.shape)      # (32,)


                # [INFO] 44'th tensor its name is "input/conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:0"
                # here perform batch normalization and here I am printing the output of this tensor
                if tensor_number == 44:
                    # here I am printing the output of this tensor
                    print(tensor_values)            # [[[[-8.45019519e-02  1.23237416e-01 -4.60943699e-01 ...
                    print(tensor_values.shape)      # (1, 320, 240, 32)

            tensor_number = tensor_number + 1
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So after running above code from console I got the input to the batch normalization which is output of "`input/conv1/conv1_1/separable_conv2d:0`" this tensor.

```
I am taking the first value from that output as x,
so, input x = -0.03182551

and beta, moving mean and moving variance is also printed on console. 
and I am take the first value from each array.
                beta = 0.04061257
                moving mean = -0.0013569
                moving variance = 4.48082483e-06
                epsilon = 0.001  ... It is default value

and gamma is ignored. because I set training time as scale = false so gamma is ignored.

When I am calculate the output of batch normalization at inference time for given input x
x_hat = (x - moving_mean) / square_root_of(moving variance + epsilon)
      = (-0.03182551 − (-0.0013569)) / √(0.00000448082483 + 0.001)
      = −0.961350647
so x_hat is −0.961350647

y = gamma * x_hat + beta
gamma is ignored so equation becomes y = x_hat + beta
                                       = −0.961350647 + 0.04061257
                                     y = −0.920738077

So If I calculated manually y at inference time it gives as y = −0.920738077
but in program it showing y = -8.45019519e-02
It is output of "input/conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:0" tensor.

It is very very different from what I am calculated. Is my equation is wrong? So which modifications 
I have to make to above x_hat and y equation so I can get this value.
```

So, I am very confused why my calculated result is very very different from resulted value ?

Also I am checked beta, moving mean and moving variance by using tf.compat.v1.global_variables(). all the values are matching with values which is printed on console for beta, moving mean and moving variance.

So why I am getting wrong result after manually substituting this values in equation `x_hat` and `y`?

Also I am providing here my console output, from tensor_number 28 to 44...

```
tensor:  28 :  input/conv1/conv1_1/separable_conv2d:0 : 
                 (1, 320, 240, 32)
[[[[-0.03182551  0.00226904  0.00440771 ... -0.01204819  0.02620635

tensor:  29 :  input/conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/Const:0 : 
                 (32,)
tensor:  30 :  conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/beta/Initializer/zeros:0 : 
                 (32,)

tensor:  31 :  conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/beta:0 : 
                 (32,)
[ 0.04061257 -0.16322449 -0.10942575  0.05056419 -0.13785222  0.4060304

tensor:  32 :  conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/beta/Assign:0 : 
                 (32,)
tensor:  33 :  conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/beta/read:0 : 
                 (32,)
tensor:  34 :  conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/moving_mean/Initializer/zeros:0 : 
                 (32,)

tensor:  35 :  conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0 : 
                 (32,)
[-0.0013569   0.00618145  0.00248459  0.00340403  0.00600711  0.00291052

tensor:  36 :  conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/moving_mean/Assign:0 : 
                 (32,)
tensor:  37 :  conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/moving_mean/read:0 : 
                 (32,)
tensor:  38 :  conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/moving_variance/Initializer/ones:0 : 
                 (32,)

tensor:  39 :  conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0 : 
                 (32,)
[4.48082483e-06 1.21615967e-05 5.37582537e-06 1.40261754e-05

tensor:  40 :  conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/moving_variance/Assign:0 : 
                 (32,)
tensor:  41 :  conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/moving_variance/read:0 : 
                 (32,)
tensor:  42 :  input/conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/Const_1:0 : 
                 (0,)
tensor:  43 :  input/conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/Const_2:0 : 
                 (0,)

tensor:  44 :  input/conv1/conv1_1/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm:0 : 
                 (1, 320, 240, 32)
[[[[-8.45019519e-02  1.23237416e-01 -4.60943699e-01 ...  3.77691090e-01
```

Comment: How are you extracting your values? Your mean is at 1e-3 with a variance of 4.5e-6, which means that a value of 0.02 is many positive standard deviations away, so a normalized value of 10 is completely reasonable in my mind for these values. I am therefore suspicious that these are not the correct values for this layer of batch norm OR your input value is incorrect, so please update your question with how you obtain these values and their input (eg. is the input normalized prior to being input into the model as well?).

Comment: Thank you for comment. Here I am shared my code which describe how I am obtained the input to batch normalization, beta, moving mean and moving variance.

Comment: I am reaching the same values as you are. Can you please print out the values of tensor 29? I think this might be your affect the values of your x tensor, but I'm not sure as it has the scope of both "input" AND Batch norm. Can you explain this?

Comment: I am resolved this problem, for batch normalization operation it uses batch mean and batch variance and beta as 0 instead of provided moving mean , moving variance and beta. So I calculated batch mean, batch variance and substitute this values in equation now it giving correct output. Thank you for help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am resolved this problem, for batch normalization operation it thinking it is in training.

So, it uses batch mean and batch variance and beta as 0 instead of provided moving mean , moving variance and beta.

So I calculated batch mean, batch variance and substitute this values in equation now it giving correct output.

So how can force him to use moving mean and moving variance and provided beta? 
I am tried with this change by setting training as false. But it is not working.

```
for tname in tens_name:         # looping through each tensor name

            if tensor_number <= 812:      # I am interested in first 812 tensors
                training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name = 'training')
                is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name = 'is_training')
                tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name(tname)
                tensor_values = sess.run(tensor, feed_dict={is_training: False, training: False, input_place: input_data})
```

in actual code is_training is true

```
def load_cnn(self,keep_prob = 0.5, num_filt = 32, num_layers = 2,is_training=True):
        self.reuse=False
        with tf.name_scope('input'):
            self.image_input=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,None,None,3],name='image_input')
            net=self.image_input

            with slim.arg_scope([slim.separable_conv2d],
            depth_multiplier=1,
            normalizer_fn=slim.batch_norm,
            normalizer_params={'is_training':is_training},
            activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,weights_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0.0, 0.01),
            weights_regularizer=slim.l2_regularizer(0.0005)):

                # Down Scaling
                # Block 1
                net=slim.repeat(net, 2, slim.separable_conv2d, num_filt, [3, 3], scope = 'conv1')
                print('en_conv1',net.shape,net.name) # 320x240x3 -> 316x236x32
                self.cnn_layer1=net
                #Down Sampling
                net=slim.max_pool2d(net,[2,2],scope='pool1') 
                print('en_maxpool1',net.shape,net.name) # 316x236x32 -> 158x118x32
```

Comment: Are your 'training' and 'is_training' actually used in the graph or are you just defining them and feeding them into the model without placing them in the graph?

Comment: is_training is used in the graph.

Comment: Because in the snippet you've provided you are defining them in your code but not putting them in the graph. Can you show where you use them in your actual code?

Comment: Instead of passing True into your function, pass the placeholder into your load_cnn function. In your first code you are creating a new 'is_training' placeholder which has no connection to the one used in your graph.

Comment: I only have a checkpoint file after loading checkpoint how I can make it as to false and use for inference.

Comment: Find the placeholder in your graph and feed that directly. I can't remember the command exactly but it should be something like the answer at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251328/tensorflow-print-all-placeholder-variable-names-from-meta-graph

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. "Find the placeholder in your graph and feed that directly".. Can you explain me more about it? How can I make it as false?

Comment: Well... the placeholder exists somewhere in your graph. You have to find that tensor so you can feed it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much.. :-)